# Would Thunderbird's cache be affected by ransomware?

Tags: email, ransomware

My university was hit by ransomware.
I wanted to know if it was possible that Thunderbird emails were also affected. (Mails saved in the cache, encrypted or not, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Thunderbird is an email *client*, so it (and its local storage) only exist on your computers. If any of *your* computers were affected by the ransomware attack, then your email data is likely affected.

If you run Thunderbird on university-maintained systems (or it stores data on a university-maintained file server), then this is a concern. Thunderbird stores a copy of your entire mailbox and all of its IMAP folders, plus all mail you store locally. If any of these systems (or any system that mounts a network filesystem that has access to this data!) was hit by the ransomware attack, you have reason to be concerned.

If the university's email *servers* were affected by the ransomware attack—and they stored user email data without encryption, then the ransomware attackers may have access to all of it.

Once you determine where your data is located, you can investigate how affected you are. Reach out to your university IT department and ask, but **be patient** as they're quite busy right now.

Generally speaking, ransomware attacks do not seek to use the stolen data at all (and they often don't have it, just the key to unlock it), **but you cannot assume this**.

Answer (score 0):

From my perspective, there is not enough information in your question to be 100% sure of what would happen, this due to the following considerations / questions:

1. The e-mail server of your University was affected by the ransomware?, or you are just talking about endpoints which have Thunderbird installed?
2. What kind of ransomware affected the University? Different ransomware variants affect different kind of files, some of them don't encrypt emails or certain file extensions.
3. If your University mail server was affected by the ransomware, and you have your local Thunderbird database in your personal computer that was not affected by the ransomware, it is not possible that during the sync process your email database will be encrypted by the ransomware (infection process). But, it is possible that during the sync process, your Thunderbird client will replace the current content with the new one in case that encrypted emails are being served by your University email server (this is not an infection process, just a syncronization process).

If you can provide more information about these aspects, we can help you with a more precise answer. But I hope the considerations mentioned above can help you to determine in what scenario are you right now.

Comment: 1.It is more precisely the computers of the university, and thus the secretariat with which I exchanged mails (I sent them sensitive documents like a photocopy of my identity card) 2. I don't know

Comment: Ok, thanks for the details. In that case, it depends on the ransomware, the majority of them try to encrypt every file they find, but there are exceptions, many of them just want to block your files but not to damage the OS (so they can show the payment info). Now remember, if you are worried about your ID card ending up in hands of cybercriminals this depends on the malware type, some malware just encrypt the files and don't send copies to the creators (majority), others like REvil ransomware, they try to steal information while encrypting it on the target computers.

Comment: To be honest, from various cases that I've seen of ransomware infections, the majority only encrypt the information, the malware does not exfiltrate any data to their creators. But that is just statistics, hope the ransomware sample that attacked your University is part of the majority samples that don't send info to cybercriminals. In case you can gather more information about the malware sample, that would be useful. Also if you have an encrypted file, you can identify the ransomware sample by uploading a file or the rescue note to this website: https://www.nomoreransom.org/en/index.html

Comment: In case you have more questions, please, do not hesitate to ask them in this website. If your doubts were already solved, please, do not forget to mark my answer as correct and upvote it. =)

Comment: Finally, if you want to learn more about ransomware that exfiltrates information, here is a good resource: https://www.cisecurity.org/blog/ransomware-the-data-exfiltration-and-double-extortion-trends/  And remember, not all ransomware do this, so don't be worried unless you are sure that the ransomware that affected your University steals info.